# Plotly JS hover info: How to hide specific info in 'x unified' hover

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I am using `hovermode: 'x unified'` in plotly.js, I want to hide the title of the hover template that consists of date, in my case.
I have looked around and found a lot of resources to modify the format for showing the info inside the template but couldn't seem to find a way to hide the title. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `hoverinfo: ['skip', 'x']`

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, the hovertemplate is the same.